# How to detect right-click on DCollapsibleCategory? [GLua]

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I believe that Garry's Mod's `DCollapsibleCategory` derives from `Panel` so I've tried to create a custom vgui element so I can add a `function PANEL:OnMousePressed(keyCode)` but that has completely changed how it draws on my scoreboard.

Here's the code for the custom vgui element, perhaps I missed something:

```
local PANEL = {}

AccessorFunc(PANEL, "hiddenPanel", "HiddenPanel")

function PANEL:Init()
    self.dataPanel = vgui.Create("DCollapsibleCategory", self)
    self.dataPanel:SetExpanded(0)
    self.dataPanel:SetLabel('')
    self.dataPanel:GetChildren()[1]:SetTall(45)
    self.dataPanel.Paint = function(pnl, w, h)
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Advocate_Scoreboard.Colors.BASE_HEADER)
    end

    self.hiddenList = vgui.Create("DPanelList", self.dataPanel)
    self.hiddenList:SetSpacing(1)
    self.dataPanel:SetContents(self.hiddenList)

    self.hiddenPanel = vgui.Create("DPanel", self.hiddenList)
    self.hiddenList:AddItem(self.hiddenPanel)
    self.hiddenPanel.Paint = function(pnl, w, h)
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, w, h, Color(50, 50, 50))
    end
end

function PANEL:PerformLayout()
    self.dataPanel:SetSize(self:GetWide(), self:GetTall())
    self.dataPanel:GetChildren()[1]:SetTall(45)

    self.hiddenList:SetSize(self.dataPanel:GetWide(), self.dataPanel:GetTall())
    self.hiddenPanel:SetSize(self.hiddenList:GetWide(), 39)
end

function PANEL:OnMousePressed(keyCode)
    print(keyCode)
end

vgui.Register("Advocate_Scoreboard.Row", PANEL)
```

`DCollapsibleCategory` doesn't respond to any `.DoClick` functions - I don't believe is has any of them methods with it deriving from Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DCollapsibleCategory](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/DCollapsibleCategory) is made up of a header row and contents.

The header [does not implement OnMousePressed](https://github.com/Facepunch/garrysmod/blob/master/garrysmod/lua/vgui/dcategorycollapse.lua#L2).

The contents is made up of whatever UI elements you add to it.
If you want the contents to respond to mouse events, you should override the [OnMousePressed](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/PANEL:OnMousePressed) for those individual elements.

If you really need this sort of functionality in the header row, you could either submit a pull request to the Garry's Mod repository.

Or alternatively:

1. Copy [the code for the DCollapsibleCategory](https://github.com/Facepunch/garrysmod/blob/master/garrysmod/lua/vgui/dcategorycollapse.lua)
2. Rename DCategoryHeader to DCategoryHeader2
3. Rename DCollapsibleCategory to DCollapsibleCategory2
4. Add the following function to the header `PANEL` table

```
local PANEL = {
    ...

    OnMousePressed = function(self, mcode)
        self.DoClick(self)
        self:GetParent():OnMousePressed(mcode)
    end,

    ...
}

derma.DefineControl( "DCategoryHeader2", "Category Header", PANEL, "DButton" )
```

And now you can detect mouse clicks on the header

```
local DCollapsible = vgui.Create( "DCollapsibleCategory2", frame )
DCollapsible:SetLabel( "Collapsible Category" )
DCollapsible:SetPos( 25, 50 )
DCollapsible:SetSize( 250, 100 )
DCollapsible:SetExpanded( false )
function DCollapsible:OnMousePressed(keyCode)
    chat.AddText("DCollapsible Key pressed- " .. tostring(keyCode))
end
```

[Full code snippet](https://gist.github.com/BadgerCode/badb586078d83a589fd85d475cc6c73a)